# Finding xml of a google play list

Tags: android, xml, rss, google-play

there any way to get xml with this list?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/featured

Apple makes something like the app strore, I think google not, but there is some way?

Thanks in advance and regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Google Play API through which you can retrieve data like this.

There is an unofficial api [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/), but it is highly limited.